# How do I move a window so that its title bar is above the visible screen area?

Tags: macos, desktop, window-manager

How can I drag/move a window so that its top is above the screen?

I want to be able to resize a window taller vertically than the screen itself, and then take a picture of the window, but I don't care about getting the window's title bar in the picture, only the content of the window, which is actually smaller than the screen but cannot all be viewed at once because of the title bar making the window's size too large.

Answer (score 1):

Enter Full Screen does exactly that. Click the green button located in the top left of most windows or type the keyboard shortcut `⌘ Cmd + CTRL + F` You will notice the title bar moves right out of the viewport.

But this can still produce a scrolling window if there is too much content.

Suggestion:

1. Drag the window down to the bottom of the screen.
2. Grab the edge of the window to stretch it taller until you reach the top of the screen.
3. Press `Cmd + Shift + 4` then `press spacebar` once. `Click` whichever window you would like to capture. Before clicking a window you will notice hovering over a window will highlight it in blue and the mouse will change to a camera.

Unfortunately, you cannot repeat 1 and 2 if the window still contains too much content. This is because on the second attempt to move the stretched window down the window is automatically reformed to fit the screen.

[image: screenshot of window at bottom of screen about to be stretched back to the top]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rotating the display will do the trick. Since screens are landscape by default, try this screen rotation hack to grab some screenshots in portrait mode. It's not really a hack so much as invoking hidden features with the keyboard and a mouse click.

1. Launch System Preferences
2. Press `Cmd + Opt` keys and click “Display” Note: this will not work if have an open System Preferences that has at some point had an active Display pane. In this case you will need to close the System Preferences window and start over with step 1.
3. Select either 90 or 180 degrees from the Rotation drop down menu.

Happy snapping.